# Are new output files created in symlinked directory or also in original directory?

Tags: symlink

I created a symlink to a directory but it seems that new output files from executing some analyses are also stored in the original directory - is this to be expected? From my understanding, the new output files should not be generated in the original directory.

Would appreciate any insight - I'd technically **not** want the original directory to be modified/added to.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a symlink to a directory, you have not created a new directory—just an alternate pathname to reference the original directory.

If you don't want any new files created in the original directory, then don't write new files to that directory.  It sounds like you want to create a new *output* directory rather than a symlink to an existing directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is only *one* directory: the original directory. The symlink is just a pointer to the original directory. So, of course, any files you create are created in the original directory.

If you don't want the original directory to be modified, you have to create a new directory and store your results in the new directory.